# Provide a msgbox when nothing is selected

Tags: vba

I wrote the following code which align all the textboxes that I have selected to the right.

```
Sub alignFunction(direction)

Dim oSel As ShapeRange
Set oSel = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange

With oSel
 .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = direction
End With

End Sub

Sub AlignRight()
 alignFunction (ppAlignRight)
End Sub
```

However if I have not selected anything it does not work and gives an error. I would like to include something so I get a pop up saying "Please select anything" in case I didnt select anything.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: put a breakpoint at the first with and look at `osel` and trap accordingly

Comment: I have never done this before, but my guess is that ActiveWindow or ActiveWindow.Selection may be null. ShapeRange would appear to be pretty dependent on Selection and I'd assume, possibly wrongly, that if Selection is set, ShapeRange is a property that is automatically set (or rather, a property that leverages what's already in place, like Count() on List<t>). I'd think it may be best to wrap around the Dim.... End With code in a if (ActiveWindow != null && ActiveWindow.Selection != null) check (not sure what that looks like in VB).

Comment: @Nathan_Sav could you please give a code exampe?

Comment: you need to debug it and check yourself, look at what Robert has suggested also.